# May I connect the RO and DI pins of a MAX485 module directly to ESP32 pins?

Tags: esp32, level-shifting, ttl

I'm running my MAX485 module board with an external 5V power supply, with the R0 and DI pins from the module connected directly to the  ESP32 pins, which running at 3.3V. Both grounds were not tied together. It runs properly, but I am concerned that the 5V TTL will damage the ESP32 pin.

I measured the RO and DI pins, reading both less than 3.2V. I have done some research and found some places saying that it should be using a level-shifting circuit to interface the MAX485 with ESP32. In other examples online they just connect them directly.

What is the correct way to connect the RO and DI pins of a MAX485 module to an ESP32?

Answer (score 1):

The [MAX485](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX1487-MAX491.pdf) appears to only operate on a 5V supply, with 5V TTL outputs and inputs.

The ESP32 [appears to not be 5V tolerant on its inputs.](https://esp32.com/viewtopic.php?t=877)  Officially, it accepts only 3.3V signals.  It also only generates 3.3V outputs. (One of the participants in that forum discussion appears to be an Espressif employee.  That person recommends against using 5V signals and refers to the ESP32 not being 5V tolerant.)

The 3.3V output from the ESP32 should do fine as an input to the MAX485.  The datasheet says the MAX485 treats anything over 2V as a high on input.  You should be able to safely connect the the ESP32 to the DI line of the module, provided there isn't a pullup resistor connceted to 5V on the module.

The 5V output of the MAX485 is outside of the ratings of the ESP32.  You should **not** connect the RO pin of the MAX485 to the ESP32.  It will damage the ESP32.

It would be safest to use a level converter for both pins.

---

Some people find that the ESP32 doesn't immediately die when connected to 5V signals.  That is not official.  It might work for you, it might work for a few days then quit, it might go up in a cloud of smoke the first time you try it.

You **must** connect the ground of the MAX485 module to the ESP32.  Without that, the signals do not have a defined level.  That could be as bad (or worse) than feeding a 5V signal to the ESP32.

Connect the grounds, use a level converter.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is if you don't have grounds connected together, they should, but it may have saved the ESP32 from frying.

ESP32 IO pins do not tolerate 5V, but they have protection trying to clamp excess current to limit voltage. The MAX485 still tries to push current while trying to output 5V. This will heat up both chips.

Generally also a 5V CMOS IC input may not understand 3.3V being fed to it, but MAX485 uses TTL levels instead of CMOS levels so this direction is OK.

Do not try mixing 5V logic with 3V logic unless being very careful.

It is best to use a level shifting circuit. And since there are many kinds of different ways to do that too, pick a suitable instead of unsuitable that creates more problems than it solves.

The websites you read may not be entirely incorrect. Some other MCUs do tolerate 5V on 3.3V IO pins.